# Как взять содержимое тега span, если id генерируется автоматически и заранее не известен?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Суть проблемы. Есть блок, который получаем некоторым способом и храним его в переменной.

> Сама переменная

```
var getDiv = document.getElementById('getDiv');
var getSpan = getDiv.innerHTML;
```

> Сам блок

```html
<div id="getDiv">
  <span id="name_наборСимволов">Текст 1</span>
  <span>Текст 2</span>
</div>
```

В getDiv лишь только один span с id, других id нет.

Вопрос вот в чём, как получить средствами js или jQuery содержимое span с id (нужно получить "Текст 1"), который генерируется автоматически (рандомно), на момент создания?

Пробовал через getSpan.find('[id^="name_"]').text(); Не помогло. Через search тот же исход.

Comment: пройди циклом по всем детям

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("#getDiv span[id]"))
```

```html
<div id="getDiv">
  <span id="name_наборСимволов">Текст 1</span>
  <span>Текст 2</span>
</div>
```